# How to Efficiently Find a Neighbor Point in a List?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, opencv, nearest-neighbor

I have a large list of Points in an Image and I want to find the Point Nearest to a given Point.

**Existing Approach Tried:**
Divide the Image into Tiles and search only within the Region of Interest by building a Table. The light blue cloured one are the points I'm comparing.

[image]
**Problems**
Even with very fewer comparisons, my algorithm is taking more than the actual time. Is there any scope for improvement in my current approach? Is there any other better approach?

Run Times in my Machine:
Time Taken for

```
FindNearestPoint  : 0.021145 ms  
FindNearestPointV2: 0.047953 ms
```

**PC Config:** Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6820HQ CPU @ 2.70 GHZ

```
// Feature Comparision.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
//
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include "Timer.h" //http://www.songho.ca/misc/timer/files/timer.zip

#include "opencv2\opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2\opencv_modules.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

bool FindNearestPoint(const Point2f Point, const vector<Point2f>vPoints, int &Index )
{
    CV_Assert(vPoints.size() != 0);

    float PrevDistance = FLT_MAX;
    Index = -1;//Error Case
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vPoints.size(); i++)
    {
        float Distance = cv::norm(Point - Point2f(vPoints[i].x, vPoints[i].y));

        if (Distance < PrevDistance)
        {
            Index = i;
            PrevDistance = Distance;
        }
    }
    return true;

}

static inline bool GetListofClustersToProcess(const Point2f Pt, const Point2f szTileSize, const Size GridSize, vector<Point> &ClusterIndices)
{
    Point Index(Pt.x* szTileSize.x, Pt.y * szTileSize.y);
    vector<Point> vClusterIndices;

    //Prev Tile
    vClusterIndices.push_back(Index + Point(-1, -1));//Prev Tile
    vClusterIndices.push_back(Index + Point(-1, 0)); //Curr Tile
    vClusterIndices.push_back(Index + Point(-1, 1)); //Next Tile

    vClusterIndices.push_back(Index + Point(0, -1)); //Prev Tile
    vClusterIndices.push_back(Index + Point(0, 0)); //Curr Tile
    vClusterIndices.push_back(Index + Point(0, 1)); //Next Tile

    vClusterIndices.push_back(Index + Point(1, -1)); //Prev Tile
    vClusterIndices.push_back(Index + Point(1, 0));     //Curr Tile
    vClusterIndices.push_back(Index + Point(1, 1));     //Next Tile

    for (size_t i = 0; i < vClusterIndices.size(); i++)
    {
        Index = vClusterIndices[i];
        if ((Index.x < 0) || (Index.x >= GridSize.width) || (Index.y < 0) || (Index.y >= GridSize.height))
        {
            continue;
        }
        ClusterIndices.push_back(Index);
    }

    return true;
}

bool FindNearestPointV2(const Point2f Point, const vector<Point2f>vPoints,const vector<vector<vector<int>>>vClusters,const Point2f szTileSize, const Size GridSize, int &Index,Mat &mDebugImage)
{
    #define EnableDebug 0

    CV_Assert(vPoints.size() != 0);

    vector<cv::Point> ClusterIndices;
    ClusterIndices.clear();

    GetListofClustersToProcess(Point, szTileSize,GridSize, ClusterIndices);

    float PrevDistance = FLT_MAX;

    Index = -1;//Error Case
    int KeypointIdx = 0;

    for (size_t iClusterIdx = 0; iClusterIdx < ClusterIndices.size(); iClusterIdx++)
    {
        cv::Point Cluster(ClusterIndices[iClusterIdx]);

        CV_Assert((Cluster.x >= 0)&&(Cluster.x < GridSize.width));
        CV_Assert((Cluster.y >= 0) && (Cluster.y < GridSize.height));

        for (size_t i = 0; i < vClusters[Cluster.y][Cluster.x].size(); i++)
        {
            KeypointIdx = vClusters[Cluster.y][Cluster.x][i];

            CV_Assert(KeypointIdx < vPoints.size());

            float Distance = cv::norm(Point - Point2f(vPoints[KeypointIdx].x, vPoints[KeypointIdx].y));

#if EnableDebug
            circle(mDebugImage, vPoints[KeypointIdx], 2, Scalar(255, 255, 0), 2);

            imshow("Input Features", mDebugImage);
#endif
            //New Optimized Implementation
            //waitKey();

            if (Distance < PrevDistance)
            {
                Index = KeypointIdx;
                PrevDistance = Distance;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    /*TestKNN();
    return 0;*/

    Size ImageSize(900, 300);
    Mat mInputImage(ImageSize, CV_8UC3, Scalar::all(0));
    RNG rng(0xFFFFFFFF);
    vector<Point2f>vKeypoints;
    int MaxNoOfKeypoints = 2000;
    uint16_t maxFilteredKeypoints = 350;
    int TileSize = 32;//Tile Size in Pixels
    Size GridSize((ImageSize.width / TileSize)+1, (ImageSize.height / TileSize)+1);
    vector<vector<vector<int>>>vClusters;
    Point ptTileIdx(0,0);
    Point2f PtQuery,PtNearestPoint, PtNearestPointV2;
    Point2f GridScale((float)GridSize.width / (float)ImageSize.width, (float)GridSize.height / (float)ImageSize.height);
    int NoOfTestPoints = 100, Iteration = 0;

    for (;;)
    {
        vKeypoints.clear();
        vClusters.clear();
        mInputImage.setTo(0);
        //Generating Random Keypoints
        for (size_t i = 0; i < MaxNoOfKeypoints; i++)
        {
            vKeypoints.push_back(Point2f(rng.uniform(0, ImageSize.width), rng.uniform(0, ImageSize.height)));
        }

        cout << "Grid Size :" << GridSize << "\n";
        for (size_t iVerTile = 0; iVerTile < GridSize.height; iVerTile++)
        {
            vector<vector<int>>HorTiles;
            Scalar color = Scalar(rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0, 255));
            for (size_t iHorTile = 0; iHorTile < GridSize.width; iHorTile++)
            {
                Rect TileRect(iHorTile*TileSize, iVerTile*TileSize, TileSize, TileSize);
                rectangle(mInputImage, TileRect, color, 1);
                color += Scalar(0, 0, 10);
                HorTiles.push_back(vector<int>());
            }
            vClusters.push_back(HorTiles);
        }
        printf("Cluster Size : %d , %d \n",vClusters.size(),vClusters[0].size());
        
        //Classify Tile Idx for all the Keypoints
        for (size_t i = 0; i < MaxNoOfKeypoints; i++)
        {
            ptTileIdx.x = (int)(vKeypoints[i].x / TileSize);
            ptTileIdx.y = (int)(vKeypoints[i].y / TileSize);
            vClusters[ptTileIdx.y][ptTileIdx.x].push_back(i);
        }

        //Displaying the Keypoints
        for (size_t i = 0; i < MaxNoOfKeypoints; i++)
        {
            circle(mInputImage, vKeypoints[i], 2, Scalar(255, 0, 0), 2);
        }
        Mat mInputTestImage = mInputImage.clone();
        Iteration = 0;
        while (Iteration<NoOfTestPoints)
        {
            PtQuery = Point2f(rng.uniform(0, ImageSize.width), rng.uniform(0, ImageSize.height));

            circle(mInputTestImage, PtQuery, 4, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
            circle(mInputTestImage, PtQuery, 2, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
            
            int NearestPointIndex = -1, NearestPointIndexV2 = -1;
            Timer t_FindNearestPt;
            t_FindNearestPt.start();

            FindNearestPoint(PtQuery, vKeypoints, NearestPointIndex);

            t_FindNearestPt.stop();

            PtNearestPoint = vKeypoints[NearestPointIndex];

            Timer t_FindNearestPtV2;
            t_FindNearestPtV2.start();
            //New Optimized Implementation
            FindNearestPointV2(PtQuery, vKeypoints, vClusters, GridScale, GridSize, NearestPointIndexV2,mInputTestImage);

            t_FindNearestPtV2.stop();

            PtNearestPointV2 = vKeypoints[NearestPointIndexV2];

            if (NearestPointIndexV2 != -1)
            {
                circle(mInputTestImage, PtNearestPointV2, 2, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 2);
            }
            if (NearestPointIndex != -1)
            {
                circle(mInputTestImage, PtNearestPoint, 2, Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
            }

            if (NearestPointIndex != NearestPointIndexV2)
            {
                printf("[Error] Closest Point not Matching! \n");
                cout << "Point" << PtQuery <<  " Org" << PtNearestPoint << "!= V2 " << PtNearestPointV2 << "\n";
                float Distance = cv::norm(PtQuery - PtNearestPoint);
                float DistanceV2 = cv::norm(PtQuery - PtNearestPointV2);
                printf("Distance : %f - %f  \n", Distance, DistanceV2);
            }
            /*else
            {
                printf("[Passed] Closest Point Matching! \n");
            }*/
            float TimeTaken_C = t_FindNearestPt.getElapsedTimeInMilliSec();
            printf("Time Taken for FindNearestPoint  : %f ms\t", TimeTaken_C);
            printf("FindNearestPointV2: %f ms\t", t_FindNearestPtV2.getElapsedTimeInMilliSec());
            printf("Speed: %f x\n", TimeTaken_C/t_FindNearestPtV2.getElapsedTimeInMilliSec());

            imshow("Input Features", mInputTestImage);
            Iteration++;
            char key = (char)waitKey();
            if (key == 27 || key == 'q' || key == 'Q') // 'ESC'
                break;
            mInputTestImage= mInputImage.clone();
        }
    
        char key = (char)waitKey();
        if (key == 27 || key == 'q' || key == 'Q') // 'ESC'
            break;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by actual time here? How was it calculated ? Is there a benchmark?

Comment: [Quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) may be useful.

Comment: You've made a good start.  You can sort the list by x or y coordinate and iterate from the ones closest to your start point, and many points can be dropped from consideration before you've even calculated the precise distance.  You'll also need to consider what happens when the tiles closest to your search point are empty.

Comment: @user3389943 Thanks for your comments! I've added my Run Times. It was quite surprising for me that it was taking almost twice the actual time!

Comment: I highly recommend using nanoflann for nearest neighbor point lookup: https://github.com/jlblancoc/nanoflann
It uses a KD-Tree and is specially designed for point cloud flavored lookups.

Comment: Trying to benchmark something that takes less than 1 second is useless, search for more points or make the set larger so it takes way more time. Also your code seems to waste time on allocating and copying vectors

Comment: @SvenNilsson Thanks for your comments on using vectors,I'll change them to Array!  Actually, I will run this loop multiple times whenever a new point comes!

Comment: Better than array may be to re-use your vector, and clear() it in between each use. Also be careful to pass vector as reference to functions, otherwise the whole thing will be copied.

Comment: How many nearest-neighbor searches do you want to perform on each image?  If you're only performing one per image then your room for improvement is pretty limited, but there are things you could try.  On the other hand, if you are performing log(N)-ish nearest-neighbor searches or more per image, then there are different things that might bring the net cost down.

Comment: for 2d points, binary space partitioning is the keyword, e.g. the kd-tree

Comment: @JohnBollinger This is happening many times inside the Feature Extraction method! So I'm running it for all the points in the list.

Comment: Have you tried removing imshow/benchmarked without EnableDebug? Additionally, instead of using std::vector in GetListofClustersToProcess, use std::array - replace the push_back with an initializer list, that reduce the necessary allocations; replace the for-loop with std::copy_if. Do you need the CV_Asserts? You might be taking a instruction cache penalty for having those.